# CSS is positioning two elements with the same class differently

Tags: html, css

I have a web form, displaying two input fields (username & password). The input fields are labelled, and the labels have their own `<div class>` in the HTML:

```
<h2>Sign in to your account</h2>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Req1" ValidationGroup="loginpage" ControlToValidate="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="loginerror" ErrorMessage="Please enter your username or email address" /><br />
<div class="fieldLabel">
    <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" Text="Username/Email" runat="server" />
</div>

<asp:TextBox ID="UserName" CssClass="id" ValidationGroup="loginpage" autocomplete="off" runat="server" /><br />
<div class="fieldLabel">
    <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" CssClass="fieldLabel" Text="Password" runat="server" /><br />
</div>
<asp:TextBox ID="Password" ValidationGroup="loginpage" autocomplete="off" TextMode="Password" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Req2" ValidationGroup="loginpage" ControlToValidate="Password" runat="server" CssClass="loginerror" ErrorMessage="Please enter your password" /><br />
```

However, despite having the same CSS class, the two labels are displayed with different positions on the form- one is indented further than the other...

In the site.css file, I have the following:

```
.loginarea .greyblock {
    background-image: url(../images/bg.gif);
    border: 1px solid #efefef;
    -webkit-border-radius: 22px;
    -moz-border-radius: 22px;
    border-radius: 22px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

    .loginarea .greyblock .fieldLabel {
        width: 300px;
        text-align: left;
        font-weight: 700;
        padding: 0px 60px;
    }
```

But although these two labels have the same CSS class applied to them, and are displayed as part of the same form, when I view the page in the browser, for some reason, one label is indented further than the other:

Why is this, and how can I fix it, so that the labels are displayed relative to the left hand side of the input fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `PasswordLabel` has the `cssClass="fieldLabel"` as well as the parent div. Have you tried removing it from the `Label`?

```
<div class="fieldLabel">
    <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" CssClass="fieldLabel" Text="Password" runat="server" /><br />
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="fieldLabel">
    <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" Text="Password" runat="server" /><br />
</div>
```

Comment: Ah yeah- spot on... Should have seen that! Thanks!